# JSON is not validating

Tags: json

I am trying to validate a json object below

```
[{"post_content":"<div class=table-responsive><table class=table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>"}, {"post_content":"<div class=table-responsive><table class=table><tr><td>
</td></tr></table></div>"}]
```

It fails. I have made it on one line like below

```
[{"post_content":"<div class=table-responsive><table class=table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>"}, {"post_content":"<div class=table-responsive><table class=table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>"}]
```

Now it works. I have more objects that cannot be edited repeatedly like this. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Monsoon, you json is invalid. see my answer for proper formatted and structured json

Answer (score 2):

According to the [RFC-4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627)

> These are the six structural characters:
>
> ```
>   begin-array     = ws %x5B ws  ; [ left square bracket
>
>   begin-object    = ws %x7B ws  ; { left curly bracket
>
>   end-array       = ws %x5D ws  ; ] right square bracket
>
>   end-object      = ws %x7D ws  ; } right curly bracket
>
>   name-separator  = ws %x3A ws  ; : colon
>
>   value-separator = ws %x2C ws  ; , comma
> ```
>
> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six
> structural characters.
>
> ```
>   ws = *(
>             %x20 /              ; Space
>             %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
>             %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
>             %x0D                ; Carriage return
>         )
> ```

In your **case 1** there is a **whitespace** next to a `<td>` which is why the json stands invalid.

In your **case 2** the same whitespace is gone and hence you have a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

The problem characters can be escaped or removed :

```js
var json = `[{"post_content":"<div class=table-responsive><table class=table><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>"}, {"post_content":"<div class=table-responsive><table class=table><tr><td>
</td></tr></table></div>"}]`

console.log( JSON.parse( json.replace(/\n/g, '\\n') ) )
```